# how to use .equalsIgnoreCase in dw 1.0 then checking uri.params?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-component, mule-esb

I have a sub flow where I want to do some action depending on uri.params values but facing issue then they are case sensitive that stop me to make a check as in some cases they come as AbcDef and sometimes as abcDef and also can be abcdef so is it possible to set value ignoring a case?
like:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
  MyKey: inboundProperties['http.uri.params'].equalsIgnoreCase(abcdef) 
}
```

so in transform component I am expecting to receive such:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
   MyKey1: inboundProperties['http.uri.params'].abcd when 
     inboundProperties['http.uri.params'].abcd != null otherwise 0
   MyKey2: inboundProperties['http.query.params'].efgh when 
     inboundProperties['http.query.params'].efgh != null otherwise 1
}
```

and then api call is:

> http://*/flowName/{abcd}?efgh=SomeString

all working fine, but if
api call is:

> http://*/flowName/{AbCd}?Efgh=SomeString

my subflow get nulls instead of values

Comment: How do you get different cases in the keys? Where are they defined?

Comment: my subflow is called by others flows and they are called by they own api endpoints so i cant control case they use for attributes, but that i know that its definitely is an attribute lets say abc and i want get it value, but if they call it Abc or aBc my code return null

Answer (score 0):

in Dataweave there's no out-of-the-box function as in Java, but there's a simple alternative using either the **upper** or **lower** functions at the boolean condition, so you can compare both strings in the same representation.

e.g.

```
key: upper(inboundProperties['http.uri.params.ID']) == "ABCDEF"
```

The documentation for the upper function can be found [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-upper)

Comment: that will be for value, in my case I dont know if key name is "ID" or "Id" or "id" and get null

Comment: Yes is for a value, you can only compare single values, http.uri.params instead returns an array, you just need to select the parameter or header that you want to compare. You can use the map function to iterate through the array and compare each element.

Comment: well my problem is that I want to find a solution how to ignore key name case to get value without case problem

Comment: The uri params is a map, so it will have key-value pairs. The keys are defined by you in the code, therefore, you must know the name of the key, as you have to declare them in your HTTP listener.

Comment: yes, but my subflow is calle by others and they dont care about case very ofthen (normaly all header attributes should be in lower case) however in our env we have mule 3.8 and its seems do case sensitive stuff, that in my case I dont needed and try to avoid dependency on the case. Yes I know name of attribute but my code fail (return null) if case dont match - and that is my problem i try to solve

Answer (score 0):

The usual method to avoid case sensitiveness is to just change everything to lower or uppercase. In my example I just change the keys of the uri params map to lower case, so any later comparison should be made to lower case strings.

Example:

```
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test/{Param1}" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
      <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/java" />
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
          %output application/json
          ---
          inboundProperties['http.uri.params'] mapObject (lower $$): lower $
          ]]>     
        </dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
```

Test:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8081/test/aBc
{
  "param1": "aBc"
}
```

Comment: in my case I don't want to change them but I want to assign it because if Param1 and i want get it value inboundProperties['http.uri.params'].param1 I will receive null, but i want to get value

Comment: I'm not sure how you define variable uri params. Are you sure it is about uri params? It sounds like you are talking about query params. The later keys are in the URL, not in the application. It would be help full to understand that.
In the meantime I have updated my example to lower the case of all uri params and leave values untouched. Note that I changed the name of the uri param to uppercase P.

Comment: its both technically, that I am try to do I want to assign to my variables attributes from uri.params and query.params, I know attribute names but I don't know they casing as some of them use camel case some of them lowercase (my favourite) and some capitalised, so basically I am looking a way how I can ignore a case then I know a name of a key in lowercase and fetch a value then

Comment: I update my question with example to make it more clear perhaps

Comment: Check my updated answer. I convert all keys to lower case then you can compare the keys as lowercase. If you want the values also just add a `lower` to the right side of the transformation. Remember that the uri params is a normal object with key, values, so you can use normal object operations in dataweave.

Comment: I see it but don't understand how to combine it together as I need convert them both and then do my logic

Comment: I have updated my example to convert both keys and values to lowercase. You can do your logic in a next component. Note that I used a JSON output for clarity, but if you are doing more logic I would use application/java to avoid parsing costs of JSON.

Comment: thanks to try to help me, but that not problem with lower case for value, its problem how to lower keys and do my logic - I am newbie in data weave and i really appreciated you help, and sorry English is not my native language so perhaps I am unclear, but that I want to understand with you example how I can adopt it to my scenario what I have above. Yes its works if I use it only to lower case, but my final result is to get variable and I don't understand how I can mix them together e.g. converting to lowercase keys for uri and query and at same time apply my logic, a bit of example please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227659/discussion-between-aled-and-gorodeckij-dimitrij).